# call equivalent of jump conditions

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

in 80x86 assembly, is there an equivalent way to use 'call' like we do with 'je' 'jl' 'jg' 'jne' ?
i want to 'call' only if a condition is met .. ?

i want to implement :

```
cmp   eax, 1
je    something
; and continuing from here
; ....
; ...
jmp   end
something:
    ret
```

using je

thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly, no -- the call instruction is always unconditional. Depending on what you're doing with je/jl/etc., you may be able to get a (somewhat) similar effect with an indirect call like `call [ebx]`, and having a jump table that contains the address of a 'null' procedure that will be called when ebx=0:

```
.code
proc1 proc
    ; whatever
null_proc::
    ret
proc1 endp

proc2 proc
   ; whatever
   ret
proc2 endp

main proc
    lea ebx, jmp_table[eax]
    call [ebx]
main endp

.data

jmp_table dd null_proc, proc1, proc2

end
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the appropriate jump command to jump to the call statement?  Have you tried that already?

Answer (score 1):

How about jumping directly to the address of the call?

```
cmp   eax, 1
je    address_of_the_call
; else code
; ....
; ....
```

Comment: what would ret do in this case ? there wasn't any 'call' to push the return address to the stack

Comment: Sorry. I copied/pasted your code without paying too much attention. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could also push the return address and jump.